# JavaScript - block external requests

Tags: javascript

so I have a app installed which is requesting/injecting a external javascript. I want to block the JavaScript, which is getting requested by the app. I wrote this in my themefile header, but the javascript seems still to be loading, and the functions from the js are still available after removing it:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function asyncLoad() { 
        console.log("test");
        $('script[src="https://static.cdn.X.com/static/js/external/shopify-product-customizer.js?v=0.17&shop=X"]').remove();
      }
    window.addEventListener("load", asyncLoad, false);     // Fails


  </script>
```

Any ideas on how to block/remove the js script?

Comment: You could look into the service worker API, that might be a way to go. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Comment: @CerebralFart shopify doesn´t allow FTP access sadly. So, I think this is not an option

Comment: In that case I think you're out of luck. As far as I know, you're only able to intercept requests using the service worker API

Comment: @CerebralFart what about modifying the loaded js in my header? Will this be an option

Comment: Once the code is loaded, it is effectively impossible to remove it. You can only disable it by intercepting the request via a service worker or by removing the script element before it starts loading. But to do the latter, the element would have to be injected dynamically.

Comment: I don´t have to remove it at all, I need to make some changes to the string´s of the loaded js. Since removing is not possible, is it possbile to change some of the content after the js got loaded

Comment: Without the service worker, you're unable to do that. And even _with_ that API, I am unsure if you could make it work